Improved a tree scheme in TikZ
Considering this MWE I ask kindly to have a best output for this scheme:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
grow=right, level 1/.style={sibling distance=2em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1em}, level distance=3.2cm,text width=2.2cm
]

\node {funzione}
  child {node {algebrica}
    child {node {razionale intera}}
    child {node {razionale fratta}}
    child {node {irrazionale}}
  }
    child {node {trascendente}
    child {node {esponenziale}}
    child {node {logaritmica}}
    child {node {goniometrica}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


what do you mean by 'best' output, please? the best output is often best because it is standard for a particular discipline or subdiscipline. obviously, legibility is part of it, but that leaves the rest wide open. (i would probably/possibly use a schema thing rather than a tree ...)

To long for the comment ...
tikz is not the best tool what you like to achieve. With it, after selecting better styles options, you can get:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
grow=right, 
level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},  % changed
level 2/.style={sibling distance=3ex, text width=7em},  % changed + added text width here
level distance=9em,  % changed
child anchor=west,      % added
]

\node {funzione}
  child {node   {algebrica}
        child {node {razionale intera}}
        child {node {razionale fratta}}
        child {node {irrazionale}}
  }
    child {node {trascendente}
        child {node {esponenziale}}
        child {node  {logaritmica}}
        child {node {goniometrica}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I would stick with @cfr suggestion (+1). To me the first suggestion is the most appealing too.

You have read my mind! Sending you a big hug back!

In the absence of further information such as target audience, disciplinary norms etc., I would use a schema rather than a tree. (Or maybe a schema is just a kind of tree with fancy edges?)
For example,

\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728764/
\usepackage{schemata}
\begin{document}
\schema{\schemabox{funzione}}{%
  \schema{\schemabox{algebrica}}{%
    \schemabox{razionale intera\\
      razionale fratta\\
      irrazionale
    }
  }
  \schema{\schemabox{trascendente}}{%
    \schemabox{%
      esponenziale\\
      logaritmica\\
      goniometrica
    }
  }
}
\end{document}

If I was going to use a tree, I would obviously use forest. I'd probably use forked edges for neatness, but I'm not entirely persuaded by the result either way, which is why I'd prefer to use schemata here.

\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728764/
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    font=\sffamily,
    anchor=parent,
    s sep'=0pt,
    tier/.option=level,
  },
  forked edges,
  [funzione
    [algebrica
      [razionale intera]
      [razionale fratta]
      [irrazionale]
    ]
    [trascendente
      [esponenziale]
      [logaritmica]
      [goniometrica]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


Thank you very much for your kind response. I wasn't familiar with the "schemata" package before. I don't often use the "forest" package or other packages for tree diagrams, although I have some understanding of the language.

Using the DOT language with the dot2texi package would be the quickest and easiest solution.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{dot2tex}[codeonly]
graph G {
    nodesep=0;
    ranksep=0;
    node[shape=plaintext];
    rankdir=LR;
    O [label="funzione"];
    O -- trascendente -- {esponenziale logaritmica goniometrica};
    O -- algebrica -- {"razionale intera" "razionale fratta" "irrazionale"};
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Note: To automatically generate the code, TeX must be configured to allow the execution of external programs. You can enable this feature by specifying an option to TeX when compiling the document. For pdflatex the option is --shell-escape. On some systems the option is called --enable-write18.
Another note: You need to install all the required dependencies mentioned in the dot2texi's documentation.

this is an interesting solution, but i don't see any evidence for the claim that it is the 'quickest and easiest'. how is that quicker or easier than forest, schemata or the automatic layout facilities of tikz's graphing libraries?

I find this approach simpler and quicker because:

Automatic Layout: Graphviz automatically lays out graphs, creating organized structures without manual adjustments. This is particularly useful for complex graphs where a node relates to sub-nodes. In DOT, I can express these relationships quicker.
Real-time Preview: Tools like GraphvizOnline offer real-time previews, allowing me to see instant changes to the DOT code. This immediate feedback speeds up the design process for complex structures.


yes, but you didn't say it was quickest/easiest for you ;). the reason I mentioned the tikz graph drawing libraries was precisely because they layout the graphs automatically using a very similar syntax to DOT, but there are no additional dependencies to install. and while I personally hate them, many tex editors now offer live updates and/or real-time previews. kile offers both, for example. I've not used them because I hate them, but live updating is now (the highly annoying) default.

Thank you for your contribution. +1
